# Insert not persisting in tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a BST, and am working on insert. I want to be able to call something simple, like `tree.insert(Node(1))`. But the issue is that this `binaryInsert` doesn't persist. What's the best way to achieve this functionality?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = data
        self.rightChild = None
        self.leftChild = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def binaryInsert(self, root, node):
        if root == None:
            root = node
        else:
            if root.value > node.value:
                if root.leftChild == None:
                    root.leftChild = node                   
                else:
                    self.binaryInsert(root.leftChild, node)
            else:
                if root.rightChild == None:
                    root.rightChild = node                  
                else:
                    self.binaryInsert(root.rightChild, node)

    def insert(self, node):
        self.binaryInsert(self.root, node)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you clarify your question.

Answer (score -1):

consider these lines from your code:

```
def binaryInsert(self, root, node):
    if root == None:
        root = node
```

here you are just overriding a local root variable (scoped to the method), I've corrected your code, feel free to ask any question:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = data
        self.rightChild = None
        self.leftChild = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def binaryInsert(self, tree, node):
        if tree.root == None:
            tree.root = node
        else:
            if tree.root.value > node.value:
                if tree.root.leftChild == None:
                    tree.root.leftChild = node                   
                else:
                    self.binaryInsert(tree.root.leftChild, node)
            else:
                if tree.root.rightChild == None:
                    tree.root.rightChild = node                  
                else:
                    self.binaryInsert(tree.root.rightChild, node)

    def insert(self, node):
        self.binaryInsert(self, node)
```